# Suggestions on identifying names with ML.Net

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ml.net

I have a trouble with anonymizing many medical reports from phonenumbers, email and also names. The phonenumbers and email I think I can get listed out by using regexp(list to verify that they are ok to be left inside the report). But for the names I need ML.Net. 
My guess it that I have a big number (ca 2000) of medical reports that contains names and some containing no names. Then I create a list of  pairs(?) consisting of the medicial files and the names found inside it.  Then I train the net on the list of pairs.

How should I look on this? 
Everything I find seems to regarding classifying pictures or something bigger(maybe I can se the text as an image and certain pattern will stand out as names, but how will I then get the names it has found?) or is it some kind of tree where names occur more frequently in a kind of branching?

I need suggestions where to look, how to look on it and what this type of classification is called.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We looked into something similar to prevent the exposure of medical PII.  You can get it to work in a general case, but there will always be really *weird* or foreign names that will not be caught by your filter (is "he" a name?  you betcha!).  You say this is related to medical reports.  I would definitely check with management / legal to see what percentage of false negatives is acceptable, because you will have false negatives.  Maybe I have misunderstood your needs?

Comment: Yes I understand what you are saying. The medical reports should already be anonymized but since humans do error I need something more and thats more through. I dont want a filter, I want to find the names by using the ML.Net to identify which series/pattern of words that most likely will have name connected to it.
Since I'am non english speaker, the "he" or "she" is not a problem for me.
If I get a list of names, then a user will mark which names are a problem in the end and which are not. False negatives might occur but my own calculation says that they will be very few.

Comment: For natural language tasks like this your best bet these days is to look at using Googles BERT and then specifically training it for your task. I also work in Health Care and I want to repeat Amy's warnings that its going to be a real struggle to get anything trained accurately enough to satisfy most organizations privacy needs. Proceed with caution.

Comment: @JerkerPihl My point with "he" was that people can have names that are identical to common, mundane words, which will make it really hard to automatically and correctly classify them as names.

Comment: Yes but I dont want to look on the name, but mostly the pattern of words it occur in. example Letter ending
`Best regards,`
`John`
If I would train on it and say it contains a name John, it should see that there is a high propability that the next following "Best regards," is a name. Not as much the name it self.